How to activate plt.show() when creating axes without pyplot in matplotlib?
I have a script like this which when executed opens up a new window with the figure.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.Figure()
# ax = fig.add_axes(rect=(0.1, 0.0, 0.9, 1.0))  # does not open a new window
ax = fig.add_subplot()  # works
plt.show()

The problem is that when I use the add_axes function, the plt.show() call seems to do nothing at all.
The fig.savefig still seems to work, but I would like to see the figure by plt.show as well. Any ideas? Thanks

Use plt.figure() instead of plt.Figure(). They are different:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()  # replaced Figure with figure
ax = fig.add_axes(rect=(0.1, 0.0, 0.9, 1.0))
ax = fig.add_subplot()  # works
plt.show()


plt.Figure() creates a new Figure object
plt.figure() creates a new Figure object and also sets it as the current figure in the pyplot state.

